# How to catch errors in protocol.ReconnectingClientFactory

Tags: twisted

I've been looking around for a solution for several hours now, and maybe I'm just missing something..

I've a factory that implements `protocol.ReconnectingClientFactory` which works just fine, however, whenever the program ends running, I get a bunch of `Unhandled error in Deferred` messages in my log for each disconnection that occurred during runtime, such as

```
2012-06-14 12:28:51+0100 [-] Unhandled error in Deferred:
2012-06-14 12:28:51+0100 [-] Unhandled Error
        Traceback (most recent call last):
        Failure: twisted.internet.error.ConnectionLost: Connection to the other side was lost in a non-clean fashion: Connection lost.
```

Is there any way I could somehow "handle" these during runtime, so that my log wouldn't be spammed with this at the end.. (or avoid it being spammed somehow..) I really don't care what the solution is, I already have the following method that logs everything for me

```
def clientConnectionLost(self, connector, reason):
        log.msg('Lost connection. Reason: %s' % reason)
```

is there anything I could do with the "reason" in there, which is the Failure object, so that the error would be properly handled..?

Anyway, I don't claim to be anywhere near proficient in Twisted, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: See http://sscce.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message `Unhandled error in Deferred` is telling you where the error comes from and even hinting at how to eliminate it.  When a `Deferred` is garbage collected with a `Failure` result, it logs these messages - because the error wasn't handled.

Add an error handler (and *errback*) to the `Deferred` that fails this way, and handle the error however you want (including ignoring it, if that's what's appropriate for your application).

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I just updated the OP with the full error message.. don't see how that helps really.. the only thing I can think of is doing something to the Failure object in the clienConnectionLost function, but not sure what? Thanks again

Comment: The update confirms my belief about the cause of the output.  There's nothing you can do about this given only a Failure.  A Deferred is logging the error.  You have to do something to the Deferred (add an error handler) to stop the message from being logged.

Comment: I'd be happy to, but how do I get that Deferred object? From what I can tell, it's not being returned by any of the involved functions.. so how to retrieve it? Cheers

Comment: I can't say I was entirely happy with this answer, but then again I can't reproduce the issue now with the latest Twisted etc., so this will just have to do. Cheers.